# Molecular Orbital Diagram of NO

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

When we draw the molecular orbital diagram for molecules

 For those that have less than or equal to 14 electrons we use the order "σ1s σ∗1s σ2s σ∗2s π2px,π2py σ2pz π∗2px,π∗2py σ∗2pz"

and for molecules that have electrons from 15 to 20 have the order "σ1s σ∗1s σ2s σ∗2s σ2pz π2px,π2py π∗2px,π∗2py σ∗2pz".

Now when we consider the case of NO or nitrogen monoxide the number of total electrons is 7+8=15 so by the above stated logic we should use the second order but from all the sources I have gone through all of them have used the first order as shown below
[image: Molecular orbital diagram of NO]

Why is this?

Comment: Can you provide a source for "For those that have less than or equal to 14 electrons we use the order "σ1s σ∗1s σ2s σ∗2s π2px,π2py σ2pz π∗2px,π∗2py σ∗2pz"
and for molecules that have electrons from 15 to 20 have the order "σ1s σ∗1s σ2s σ∗2s σ2pz π2px,π2py π∗2px,π∗2py σ∗2pz". ?

Comment: Problem is, the amount of molecular orbitals will depend on the amount of electrons (basic maths here), yet their order is a matter of energy only (I think that's the point of @Andrew's question)

Comment: there isn't a very solid source really this is a portion that is covered in the coaching institution I go for and the same had uploaded this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtQPh49fWeI&list=PL7AAT-ai0VD6O25hUm8BpberRzhdBK9ej&index=5) about the same and around the time stamp 24:10 they get into the molecular orbital diagram and just a disclaimer the video is partially in hindi though